# IRLBot Paper DRUM Implementation - Why keep Key, Value pairs and Auxiliary buckets separate?

Tags: c++, file-io, web-crawler

I'm trying to implement DRUM (Disk Repository with Update Management) in Java as per the  [IRLBot paper](http://irl.cs.tamu.edu/people/hsin-tsang/papers/www2008.pdf) (relevant pages start at 4) but as quick summary it's essentially just an efficient way of batch updating (key, value) pairs against a persistent repository. In the linked paper it's used as the backbone behind the crawler's `URLSeen` test, `RobotsTxt` check and DNS cache.

There has helpfully been an implementation in c++ done  [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36221/DRUM-A-C-Implementation-for-the-URL-seen-Test-of-a#_comments), which lays out the architecture in a much more digestable way. For ease of reference, this is the architecture diagram from the c++ implementation:

[image: Architecture of DRUM]

The part which I'm struggling to understand is the reasoning behind keeping the (key, value) buckets and auxiliary buckets separate. The article with the c++ implementation states the following:

> During merge a key/value bucket is read into a separate buffer and
>   sorted. Its content is synchronized with that of the persistent
>   repository. Checks and updates happen at this moment. **Afterwards, the
>   buffer is re-sorted to its original order so that key/value pairs
>   match again the corresponding auxiliary bucket.** A dispatching
>   mechanism then forwards the key, value and auxiliary for further
>   processing along with the operation result. This process repeats for
>   all buckets sequentially.

So if the order of the (key, value) buckets need to be restored to that of the auxiliary buckets in order to re-link the (key, value) pairs with the auxiliary information, why not just keep the (key, value, aux) values together in singular buckets? What is the reasoning behind keeping them separate and would it be more efficient to just keep them together (since you no longer need to restore the original unsorted order of the bucket)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On merge-time DRUM loads the content of the key/value disk file of the respective bucket and depending on the operation used checks, updates or check+updates every single entry of that file with the backing datastore.

The auxiliary disk file is therefore irrelevant and not loading the auxiliary data into memory simply saves some memory footprint while sorting which DRUM tries to minimize in order to process the uniqueness of more than 6 billion entries. In case of f.e. the RobotsCache the auxiliary data can be even some 100kb per entry. This is however only a thesis on my own, if you really want to know why they separated these two buffers and disk-files you should probably ask Dmitri Loguinov.

I've also create a Java based [DRUM implementation](https://github.com/RovoMe/JDrum) (also a Java-based [IRLbot implementation](https://github.com/RovoMe/JIRLbot)), but both might need a bit more love though. There is also a further Java-based Github project called [DRUMS](http://mgledi.github.io/DRUMS/) which extends DRUM with a select feature which was used to store genome codes.

Comment: Hi Roman, coincidentally I stumbled across your DRUM/IRLBot implementations a while ago! I think you are right, this is quite a specific question so probably a question for the researcher, I may drop him a line. Thanks a lot.